# Jruby error (wrong name: ruby/jit/FILE_D40BB14F6D953C9F0017A388A07364EC0E5B3F6E)

Tags: java, jruby

I am trying to compile a file using jruby with the following commands but I have not had any luck.

```
    jruby -S jrubyc test5.rb 
    java -cp .:/Users/Ted/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.2/lib test5
```

I get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test5 (wrong name: ruby/jit/FILE_D40BB14F6D953C9F0017A388A07364EC0E5B3F6E)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:698)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:315)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:330)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:250)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
```

Ted

Answer (score 0):

You need to [package your class in a `jar` file.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Also, your `-cp` argument needs to specify an actual jar file (or zip) - it cannot refer to a directory as in your example.